# How to use relative path of file in eclipse plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, relative-path

I want to find the relative path of a file in my eclipse plugin project.

Need to know the Workspace of the Eclipse in which plugin project exists, not the workspace of the eclipse plugin runtime Application.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getCurrentWorkspaceLocation() {
    IWorkspace workspace = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace();
    URL url = Nameofyourcurrentclass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource()
            .getLocation();
    System.out.println(url);
    java.io.File workspaceDirectory = workspace.getRoot().getLocation()
            .toFile();
    System.out.println(workspaceDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Output:

```
file:/Users/amanpreetkaur/Downloads/eclipse/../../Documents/workspace_old/SpreadSheetUpdater/

/Users/amanpreetkaur/Documents/runtime-EclipseApplication
```

First is the path of workspace in which plugin project exists.
Second is the path of Eclipse launched by running plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static InputStream getFileStream(IPath pluginRelativeFilePathToGet) {
    URL fileURL = yourPlugin.getBundle()
                    .getResource(pluginRelativeFilePathToGet.toOSString());
    URLConnection connection = fileURL.openConnection();
    return connection.getInputStream();
}
```

This will return InputStream of the plugin relative file.
You can easily create a File from this stream.

Regards
Sargis